# architecture on google cloud platform for scientific web application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pandas, architecture, google-compute-engine

I have an apps coded in python/pandas/scipy which can be launched by anyone authorized. I want to use Google Cloud Platform to  host it but I can't find a good way to set up this.

Since I want my app to be a web app, part of this is hosted on google app engine, but since google app engine does not seem compatible with big calculus and scientific libraries, I think I shall send the task to a VM with the scientific libraries.

My questions are:
1- could I create a VM each time the app is launched, in order to save money? But if I do this, I have to setup pandas scipy etc... each time, which should take some time?

2- Am I condemned to have a VM running every time and activated by the app? But if two people launch the calculus together, this can be really bad perf?

3 - Shall I package my app as a .exe and launch it as a standalone?

I am totally lost on how to handle such an architecture, can anyone give me some advices?

Thank you!

Comment: you need to use compute engine, separate out the computation and the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your application on [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/). Applications that run on managed VMs are not subject to the restrictions imposed on the sandboxed runtimes (Java, Python, PHP, and Go).

You can also choose the hosting environment (sandboxed or managed VM) separately for each module in your application. This means an application can contain a mix of modules that use different hosting environments. For instance, you might use the sandbox environment for your client-facing frontend, and use a module running in a managed VM for backend processing.

Comment: Your answer is very interesting and I did not know about Managed VMs untill now. Do you have some sample project or coded examples which includes this mixing sandbox and managed VM you are talking about?

Comment: I also see that this is a beta service, and only US apps can use it. Since I am in Europe, would you have another architecture advice, like a plan B?

Comment: You can find a few sample projects on this article:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/#testing_and_deploying_managed_vms

Comment: To answer your question, I suggest reading this blog post:  http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2014/03/bringing-together-best-of-paas-and-iaas.html